# Action centre activated in pockets

Tags: lock-screen, action-center

It's possible to access the features of the action centre on a windows phone without unlocking the device. Also, when you receive a notification, the phone screen turns on. A combination of those two factors means that when I get a notification while my phone is in my pocket, my pocket or body tends to press buttons in the action centre. There's quite a lot of "dangerous" buttons in the action centre, so I'll often take my phone out and find that the flashlight and airplane mode has been turned on. I'm worried that I miss an important messages messages because airplane mode has been turned on, and that people will think I'm mad for keeping a flashlight on in my pockets.

I've set a lock screen code which prevents unintended use past the action centre, but the action centre itself is more than I'd like to accidentally play with.

Does anyone else have this problem? How do you solve it? It would be great if you could prevent the screen from activating when a notification comes through, I don't know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the notifications appearing in action centre when phone is locked. This should stop your phone from turing on the screen when you receive a notification.

You can view all these notifications when you unlock your phone.

**To turn it off for all apps,**

1. Go to *Settings -> System -> Notifications & actions*.
2. Turn off the toggle for *Show notifications in action centre when phone is locked*.

**To turn it off a particular app**,

1. Go to *Settings->System-> Notifications & actions*.
2. Choose an app.
3. Turn on the toggle for *Keep notifications private on lock screen*.

Comment: Turning off "show notifications in the action centre when phone is locked" does not solve the issue, screen still activates when messages come through.

Comment: @MathewSainsbury Yes, your screen will go on for messages and phone calls. There only way to turn it off would be to turn off notifications for messages completely. If you that you will important messages. After doing the steps in my answer your phone screen will not be activated for whatsapp messages, etc...